# Моделирование автоматического боя для двух игроков

Tags: python, ajax, php, gameserver, django

Я Вас приветствую.

Для саморазвития (а может быть, и не только, кто знает...) делаю мини-игру, 2 бойца выставляются на бой игроками, но бойцы дерутся сами, по раундам (боец может ударить один раз за раунд). Сейчас реализовано на РНР.

Из-за реализации чистого РНР каждое обращение на сервер (например, ajax-ом) создает раунд, в этом раунде происходят события. Возвращаются результаты раунда. Если не задавать случайные идентификаторы, у каждого игрока будет свой набор результатов, причем сообщение об окончании боя придет только одному. Каждое обращение десериализует множество объектов, что довольно сильно нагружает сервер, и ежесекундное обращение каждого игрока ajax-ом может его перегрузить (на моем нетбуке сервер отвечает около секунды).

Я начал задумываться о смене технологии. Смотрю в сторону Python и Django.

Можно ли с помощью данного фреймворка запустить фоновый процесс, который будет, например, беспрерывно вести бой (с задержкой между ударами и раундами), результаты раунда записывать в базу? А обращение клиента на сервер будут брать только результаты из базы, не генерируя никаких дополнительных событий.

Возможно, есть какое-то более элегантное решение?

Comment: А что мешает сделать то же самое на PHP? Зачем сразу язык менять?

Comment: Возможно, Вам поможет многопоточность. https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html http://habrahabr.ru/post/149420/